# google chrome error on html5 drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I try to implement something with jquery and html5 native drag and drop.

```
obj.attr("draggable", "true")
        .addClass("initialized")
        .on("dragstart", function(ev) {

            var res = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', "my text");

            console.log(res, "--", ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));

            ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        });
```

After i run this code in firebug console i have this output:

> true "--" "my text"

and all works fine, but in chrome the output is

> true "--" undefined

I really don't understand where is the problem. It seams that chrome does not know how to read data. Does anybody have an ideea to make this work on chrome, too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue and I've found that HTML5 specifications for Drag'n'Drop are confusing.

You can use only `setData` in `dragstart`

and you can use only `getData` in drop

for other events, you should parse what type of data are available (not tested yet) but not content.

Check [dndevents](http://developers.whatwg.org/dnd.html#dndevents) and 'protected mode'